# how to get data from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase

how can i get data from firebase Realtimedatabase?
i very new on Android an have no plan how to do this. can someone suggest me?

is this ok?

```
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
    Post newPost = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
    System.out.println("Author: " + newPost.author);
    System.out.println("Title: " + newPost.title);
    System.out.println("Previous Post ID: " + prevChildKey);
  }

  @Override
  public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

  @Override
  public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

  @Override
  public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "is this ok"? Is that code running? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this:

```
DatabaseReference.getInstance().getReference("user").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Child child = dataSnapshot.getValue(Child.class);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
    });
```